# How to quote bulleted lists using IEEE style?

Tags: citation-style, ieee, quotation

I found two very useful bulleted lists in my sources and I want to quote them directly in my thesis. For example:

> - *Sentence 1*
> - *Sentence 2*
> - *Sentence 3*
> - *Sentence 4*

Nevertheless I only could find how to do it using [APA](http://askus.baker.edu/faq/217223) and [MLA](https://penandthepad.com/use-intext-citation-bullet-points-mla-4757.html). How can I do this using IEEE style?

**EDIT**: I was following the approach proposed by the accepted answer, but I found two awkward consequences while doing this. I would appreciate if someone can confirm if this approach is okay. I explain the problem with an example.

Consider this list in the original source:

- sold, leased, or licensed to the general public
- offered by a vendor trying to profit from it
- supported and evolved by the vendor, who retains the intellectual property rights
- available in multiple, identical copies
- used without modification of the internals

Lists are automatically indented. Quoting this list directly using the IEEE guidelines will increase the indentation of the list:

> - sold, leased, or licensed to the general public
> - offered by a vendor trying to profit from it
> - supported and evolved by the vendor, who retains the intellectual property rights
> - available in multiple, identical copies
> - used without modification of the internals [1, Sec. 1.1]

Furthermore we have to add the in-text citation at the end of the long quotation, but because it is added at the last item in the list it might confuse the reader regarding what is actually quoted: the complete list or the last item. Is this okay?

Comment: Put it in a block quote and cite it like you would any other quote.

Comment: @ScottSeidman would you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Put it in a block quote and cite it like you would any other quote. The fact that it's a bulleted list doesn't necessarily  make it special.

Comment: Usually the bulleted lists are automatically indented. If I put them in a block quote should I indent them further?